# Am I able to friend Java players on Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

One of my friends has a realm, and I wanted to join it. He said he didn't have me whitelisted, so I told him that I could just add him through a cubecraft server. He said it wouldn't work, but I'm sure I've done it, before.

Am I able to friend Java players on Windows 10?

Comment: The practical answer: Bedrock edition is missing a lot of content compared to the Java edition. So just switch to Java and never look back :)

Answer (score 6):

Java players can't join others in bedrock servers, due to some differences in physics, giving unfair advantages to java and bedrock players. The 2 games [bedrock and java edition] are also coded in different languages. It won't work.

Comment: There is a [program](https://geysermc.org/) that allows limited gameplay on Java Edition servers for Bedrock Edition clients. Nothing in the opposite direction, so if it's a BE realm, this won't work.

Comment: I would like to point out that the language the editions are written in has nothing to do with why there is no communication between the editions. There's just nothing coded into either edition to allow cross-edition gameplay. It's possible to make it work, but inefficient. Also, the biggest reason they wouldn't allow cross-edition gameplay is as you stated, that Java edition gives unfair advantages to players.

Comment: @Tacoタコス I suspect the biggest reason is that it would take too many (programmer) resources to add the cross-compatibilty in properly - there's nothing saying they couldn't alter the rules of one or the other to make it fair; it's just a huge amount of *work* and not really in Mojang/Microsoft's interests as for the most part they'd rather everyone play Bedrock, I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

No. The social systems in the Java and Bedrock versions are not linked. It is not possible for Java clients to connect to Bedrock servers, nor is it possible for Bedrock clients to connect to Java servers. Some of this might change in the future as Mojang accounts are migrated to Microsoft accounts.